# Layer error: Image.rename: The number of names (1) must match the number of bands (10)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, flood, landsat-7

I am using Landsat 7 data (ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA")) for flood mapping. I am trying to write the code but I'm stuck at a line where it says "Layer error: Image.rename: The number of names (1) must match the number of bands (10)". I'm posting the code below.

```
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'grey'}, 'Brahmani District');
////

//mask clouds
function maskLandsatclouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('BQA')
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(4).int()
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  return image.updateMask(mask)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}

var before = collection.filterBounds(geometry)
                .filterDate('2000-11-01','2001-04-30')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUD_COVER", 0.1))
                .filterBounds(geometry)
                .map(maskLandsatclouds)

print(before.size(),'Number of Images in the collection');
print(before,'before_collection');


var mosaic_before = before.mosaic().clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(mosaic_before,{bands:['B3','B2','B1']},'Mosaic_before')
////
///var first_image = before.first();
///print(first_image,'First Image')
///Map.addLayer(first_image,{bands:['B3','B2','B1']},'First image from collection');
////

//mask clouds2
function maskLandsatclouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('BQA')
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(4).int()
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  return image.updateMask(mask)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}

var after = collection.filterBounds(geometry)
                .filterDate('2001-06-01','2002-02-20')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUD_COVER", 0.1))
                .filterBounds(geometry)
                .map(maskLandsatclouds)

print(after.size(),'Number of Images in the collection');
print(after,'after_collection');


var mosaic_after = after.mosaic().clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(mosaic_after,{bands:['B3','B2','B1']},'Mosaic_after')

/////Till this point everything is correct


var difference = mosaic_after.divide(mosaic_before).clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(difference, {min:0, max:1}, 'Flood Area', false);


/////
// Define a threshold
var diffThreshold = 1.25;
// Initial estimate of flooded pixels
var flooded = difference.gt(diffThreshold).rename('water').selfMask();
Map.addLayer(flooded, {min:0, max:1, palette: ['orange']}, 'Initial Flood Area', false);


// Mask out area with permanent/semi-permanent water
var permanentWater = gsw.select('seasonality').gte(5).clip(geometry)
var flooded = flooded.where(permanentWater, 0).selfMask()
Map.addLayer(permanentWater.selfMask(), {min:0, max:1, palette: ['blue']}, 'Permanent Water')

// Mask out areas with more than 5 percent slope using the HydroSHEDS DEM
var slopeThreshold = 5;
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(hydrosheds);
var slope = terrain.select('slope');
var flooded = flooded.updateMask(slope.lt(slopeThreshold));
Map.addLayer(slope.gte(slopeThreshold).selfMask(), {min:0, max:1, palette: ['cyan']}, 'Steep Areas', false)

        
// Remove isolated pixels
// connectedPixelCount is Zoom dependent, so visual result will vary
var connectedPixelThreshold = 8;
var connections = flooded.connectedPixelCount(25)
var flooded = flooded.updateMask(connections.gt(connectedPixelThreshold))
Map.addLayer(connections.lte(connectedPixelThreshold).selfMask(), {min:0, max:1, palette: ['yellow']}, 'Disconnected Areas', false)

Map.addLayer(flooded, {min:0, max:1, palette: ['red']}, 'Flooded Areas');
```

Link for the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2FTanmoy_Majumder%2FBrahmani_Flood%3APractice_12-04-22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var flooded = difference.gt(diffThreshold).rename('water').selfMask();
```

`difference` has multiple bands. When I look back to see where it came from, I find `maskLandsatclouds()` which did `.select("B.*")` — selecting multiple bands. You will need to change your code, either in `maskLandsatclouds()` or after it, to select the **single** band that you want to calculate with and rename to `"water"`.

Comment: Can you please suggest the modified code that I should use in the script. It would be very helpful.

Comment: @TanmoyMajumder I cannot tell you that because I don't know which band you want to use in your calculation. It will involve inserting a `.select()` call somewhere before `.rename()` but *you* have to choose the right band.